# how to get line offset in StreamTokenizer?

Tags: java, stream, bufferedreader

I am working on a parser for my class that uses the `StreamTokenizer` class in java. In the case of a parsing error, I want to be able to print the exact line and offset of the character that begins the token where the error occurred. However, while the `StreamTokenizer` has a `lineno()` method to find which line the tokenizer is at, there is no method to find the character offset within that line.

I am hoping that somehow there is a way to get this offset using the available functions in either `StreamTokenizer` or `BufferedReader`, the input to the `StreamTokenizer` constructor.

So far, I have tried using something like this:

```
BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(dataReader);
st.eolIsSignificant(true);
```

Then, I made a wrapper around the

```
 StreamTokenizer.nextToken()
```

function so that it looks something like this:

```
 public int nextTokenSpec(StreamTokenizer st) throws IOException{
        int token = st.nextToken();

        if (token == StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL){
            Linker2.offsetCounter = 0;
            token = st.nextToken();
        } else{
            Linker2.offsetCounter += st.sval.length();
        }
        return token;
    }
```

note that `Linker2` is a driver class that contains the main function where the above code (`BufferedReader` and `StreamTokenizer`) are invoked.

However, the problem with this is that it ignores the token delimiters, as it only increments based on the length of the tokens.

I suspect there may be some way to go directly to the `BufferedReader` to get info on this, but I am not sure.

Does anyone know how I can get the exact line offset of the `StreamTokenizer` function?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't get the exact line / character offset using a `StringTokenizer`.  You need to use a different mechanism for tokenizing.

> I suspect there may be some way to go directly to the BufferedReader to get info on this, but I am not sure.

That wouldn't work reliably.  The `StringTokenizer` needs to read ahead to (try to) find the end of the current token or the next token (if you call `hasMoreTokens()`).  The position recorded in the reader is the "high water mark" for read-ahead, not the start of a token.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Stephen. What would you recommend that would allow me to tokenize an input file and accurately record the offset of a parsing error? I was thinking of reading the file line-by-line, but the problem is that the line endings have no special meaning, and since I am using a top-down "predictive" parser, I need to be able read specific tokens/sets of tokens in chunks, which seemed like it would make handling line endings a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for getting the token’s position inside the line and there’s no reliable way to work-around this. But you may consider replacing the `StreamTokenizer` as its encapsulated pattern matching isn’t very advanced anyway. You may stumble upon other deficiencies in the future, which you also can’t workaround, while they are easy to do better if you are in control of the patterns. I’m not talking about reinventing the wheel, but using regular expressions instead:

```
public static void parseStreamTokenizer(String filename) throws IOException {
    try(Reader r=new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(r);) {
        StreamTokenizer st=new StreamTokenizer(dataReader);
        for(;;) {
            double d=Double.NaN;
            String w=null;
            switch(st.nextToken()) {
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF: return;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL: continue;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER: d=st.nval; break;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD: case '"': case '\'': w=st.sval; break;
            }
            consumeToken(st.lineno(), -1, st.ttype, w, d);
        }
    }
}
static final Pattern ALL_TOKENS = Pattern.compile(
     "(-?(?:[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.[0-9]*))"       // number
   +"|([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]*)"        // word
   +"|([\"'])((?:\\\\?.)*?)\\3" // string with backslash escape
   +"|/.*"        // StreamTokenizer's "comment char" behavior
   +"|\\s*"        // white-space
);
public static void parseRegex(String filename) throws IOException {
    try(Reader r=new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(r)) {
        String line;
        int lineNo=0;
        Matcher m=ALL_TOKENS.matcher("");
        while((line=dataReader.readLine())!=null) {
            lineNo++;
            m.reset(line);
            int last=0;
            while(m.find()) {
                double d=Double.NaN;
                String word=null;
                for(int e=m.start(); last<e; last++) {
                    consumeToken(lineNo, last+1, line.charAt(last), word, d);
                }
                last=m.end();
                int type;
                if(m.start(1)>=0) {
                    type=StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER;
                    String n=m.group();
                    d=n.equals(".")? 0: Double.parseDouble(m.group());
                }
                else if(m.start(2)>=0) {
                    type=StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD;
                    word=m.group(2);
                }
                else if(m.start(4)>=0) {
                    type=line.charAt(m.start(3));
                    word=parse(line, m.start(4), m.end(4));
                }
                else continue;
                consumeToken(lineNo, m.start()+1, type, word, d);
            }
        }
    }
}
// the most complicated thing is interpreting escape sequences within strings
private static String parse(String source, int start, int end) {
    for(int pos=start; pos<end; pos++) {
        if(source.charAt(pos)=='\\') {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(end-start+16);
            sb.append(source, start, pos);
            for(; pos<end; pos++) {
                if(source.charAt(pos)=='\\') {
                    int oct=0;
                    switch(source.charAt(++pos)) {
                        case 'n': sb.append('\n'); continue;
                        case 'r': sb.append('\r'); continue;
                        case 't': sb.append('\t'); continue;
                        case 'b': sb.append('\b'); continue;
                        case 'f': sb.append('\f'); continue;
                        case 'v': sb.append('\13'); continue;
                        case 'a': sb.append('\7'); continue;
                        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3':
                            int next=pos+1;
                            if(next<end && (source.charAt(next)&~'7')==0)
                                oct=source.charAt(pos++)-'0';
                            // intentionally no break
                        case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7':
                            oct=oct*8+source.charAt(pos)-'0';
                            next=pos+1;
                            if(next<end && (source.charAt(next)&~'7')==0)
                                oct=oct*8+source.charAt(pos=next)-'0';
                            sb.append((char)oct);
                            continue;
                    }
                }
                sb.append(source.charAt(pos));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
    return source.substring(start, end);
}
// called from both variants, to the same result (besides col values)
static void consumeToken(int line, int col, int id, String word, double number) {
    String type;
    Object o;
    switch(id)
    {
        case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER: type="number"; o=number; break;
        case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD: type="word"; o=word; break;
        case '"': case '\'': type="string"; o=word; break;
        default: type="char"; o=(char)id;
    }
    System.out.printf("l %3d, c %3s: token %-6s %s%n",
            line, col<0? "???": col, type, o);
}
```

Note that `parseStreamTokenizer` and `parseRegex` produce the same result (I let them parse their own source code), the only difference being that `parseRegex` is capable of providing the column number, i.e position within a line.

What makes the code look complicated is the attempt to reproduce the same result as `StreamTokenizer`, as you didn’t specify more about your actual use case. I don’t know whether you actually need non-standard escape sequences like `\v` and `\a` or octal escapes in strings or whether you really want a single dot to be interpreted as `0.0` or whether all numbers should be provided as `double` values, but that’s what the `StreamTokenizer` does.

But I suppose, for every practical use case, your parser will sooner or later require capabilities that exceeds `StreamTokenizer`’s (beyond column numbers) anyway, making using the more complicated code unavoidable. On the other hand, it also provides you with more control and allows getting rid of unneeded things, so the above code should provide a good starting point…